# Getting a chart to appear in a UI after taking in info from the user

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a UI web app in google apps script which access a database in a spreadsheet, manipulates the data and then puts it into a chart. Now my problem is that I get get the chart to be displayed back into the Ui. I don't even know if that is a possibility, but something along those lines. This is what i have tried thus far:

1. First I created a chart in the doGet function and then tried to
   access and edit after i took in some info from the user. The problem
   was that when i .build() the chart it become a generic object and
   cannot be edited.

   Second I tried to .add the chart to the Ui after taking in info, but
   i could not get the ui to update. again i don't know the right way
   to do this.

Let me know if you need any additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the UI to update you need to ensure that you return the application (UiInstance) in the handler function.